# Drawing line by finger android

Tags: android, line, draw

I make a puzzle in android and for find the words the user need cross to word. For drawing I think I need use canvas. But I would only right, left, above or below line.

How can I make line in android?

I need your help.

Comment: You want to draw a cross or a simple line?

Comment: @GOVINDDIXIT a simple line

Answer (score 2):

I write the following code in SOF editor, so you'd probably need to shape it up a bit in your Android Studio.

The main idea is: use the `Path` to track the move path of finger. Then draw the path in `onDraw`.

In your view:

```java
Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.Style.ANTI_ALIAS);
Path path = new Path();

@Override
public boolean onTouch(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        path.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
        break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        path.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
        invalidate();
        break;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.draw(path, paint);    
}
```

If you need support multi fingers, let me know I can post more codes.

---

**UPDATE**

Code sample for multiple finger move to draw lines:

```java
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import com.chinalwb.multitouchview.Utils;


import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class MultiTouchView3 extends View {

    private Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    private SparseArray<Path> paths = new SparseArray<>(5);

    public MultiTouchView3(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    {
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(Utils.dp2px(5));
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        for (int i = 0; i < paths.size(); i++) {
            canvas.drawPath(paths.valueAt(i), paint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int actionIndex = event.getActionIndex();
        int pointerId = event.getPointerId(actionIndex);
        Log.e("XX", "pointer id == " + pointerId);

        switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                Path path = new Path();
                path.moveTo(event.getX(actionIndex), event.getY(actionIndex));
                paths.put(pointerId, path);
                Log.e("XX", "paths size == " + paths.size());
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
                    pointerId = event.getPointerId(i);
                    Path pointerPath = paths.get(pointerId);
                    pointerPath.lineTo(event.getX(i), event.getY(i));
                }
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                path = paths.get(pointerId);
                if (null != path) {
                    paths.remove(pointerId);
                    invalidate();
                }
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

You can comment out `case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:` and `case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:` if you only want to support single finger.

Comment: I get 2 errors: https://i.hizliresim.com/LvZGaJ.png I don't would multiple fingers.

Comment: @AhmetVeli, the other answer is correct, you can refer to that one

Comment: You'll want to check your build environment

Answer (score 2):

You just need to handle the drawing inside your View `onTouchEvent`. Whenever you touch the screen, draw the line until you untouch the screen.

```
public class DrawingView extends View {

  private Paint mPaint;
  private Path mPath;

  public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    mPath = new Path();
  }

  @Override 
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
  }

  @Override 
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {

      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        mPath.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
        break;

      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        mPath.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
        invalidate();
        break;

      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        break;
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

The above is a running sample of a basic drawing line in a View. You need to customize it further according to your own need.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Kotlin version of LiuWenbin_NO.'s answer, to save time :)

```java
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.graphics.Path
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.View

class DrawingView @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context,
                                             attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0)
    : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private val mPaint: Paint = Paint()
    private val mPath: Path = Path()
    
    init
    {
        mPaint.apply {
            color = Color.RED
            style = Paint.Style.STROKE
            strokeJoin = Paint.Join.ROUND
            strokeCap = Paint.Cap.ROUND
            strokeWidth = 10f
        }
    }
    
    // Called when the view should render its content.
    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        canvas!!.drawPath(mPath, mPaint)
    }
    
    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean
    {
         when(event?.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                mPath.moveTo(event.x, event.y)
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                mPath.lineTo(event.x, event.y)
                invalidate()
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```